# Getting wrong answer after performing mathematical operations

Tags: java

I am trying to perform some mathematical calculations in java but the expected result is not getting. Since the same snippet of the code when I run in "C" programme then it works correctly please guide me what is getting wrong in the code.

The value that is getting passed to the function is.

```
v0=1970012 and v1=1970012 and iterations= 32
```

The "C" Programme snippet looks something like this

```
void encipher(uint8_t iterations, uint32_t v0, uint32_t v1)
{
    uint8_t i;

     int key[]={0x02a4bd14,0x6c753bde,0x4ac819ad,0x6da4a0c4};




     uint32_t sum, delta;

      sum=0x32d61b8e;
       delta=0x9E3779B9;
      for (i=0; i < iterations; i++) {
      v0 += (((v1 << 4) ^ (v1 >> 5)) + v1) ^ (sum + key[sum & 3]);
      sum += delta;
       v1 += (((v0 << 4) ^ (v0 >> 5)) + v0) ^ (sum + key[(sum>>11) & 3]);
   }
      en_result0=v0; en_result1=v1;
 }
```

The en_result0 and en_result1 are the global varaibles and are of the same type as v0 and v1

Similarly the Java snippet code looks something like this.

```
public static void encipher(int iterations, int v0, int v1)
 {
     int i;
int key[]={0x02a4bd14,0x6c753bde,0x4ac819ad,0x6da4a0c4};
     int sum, delta;
     sum=0x32d61b8e;
      delta=0x9E3779B9;
  for (i=0; i < iterations; i++) {
   v0 += (((v1 << 4) ^ (v1 >> 5)) + v1) ^ (sum + key[sum & 3]);
   sum += delta;
   v1 += (((v0 << 4) ^ (v0 >> 5)) + v0) ^ (sum + key[(sum>>11) & 3]);
  }
  en_result0=v0; en_result1=v1;
```

}

Here also the en_result0 and en_result1 are global variables of type int

```
The answer in "C" programme en_result0=3755627302 and en_result1=3278396279
```

And

```
The Answer in "java" Programme en_result0=-1152914223 and en_result1=1706153302
```

Just not Find where is getting wrong Please Help me to find The solution

Comment: Well, one thing you'll need to keep in mind that Java doesn't have unsigned variables. That'll affect some things (especially the displaying of the values).

Comment: Remind that `int` in Java is signed - there is no exact counterpart to C's insigned int types

Comment: i am just confused in this signed and unsigned issue

Comment: they're saying that an unsigned int (ie, only positive) can store larger values than a signed int (that can be positive/negative).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get the correct results when you replace the >> operator by Java's >>> operator. It does an unsigned right shift, just what the C code achieves with declaring unsigned variables and doing right shifts.

The other operations are harmless and give the same results, no matter if signed or unsigned.

Note that to print the results, you should do something like:

```
println( ((long) result) & 0xFFFFFFFFL ); // where result is int
```

or use an appropriate printf format (i.e. print it in hex).

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that the C code is using unsigned integer types, whereas the Java code is using signed types (there are no unsigned integers in Java).

One possibility is to use Java's `long` in place of C's `uint32_t`. It's signed but is double the width. You may also need to change the types of `v0`, `v1`, `en_result0` and `en_result1` to avoid integer overflow.

Comment: Though those bit shifts with the additional size might also get you a different answer, it might work to just `& 0xFFFFFFFF` it at the end.

Comment: i had tried with the "long" also still not getting the right answer

Comment: you mean anding with the en_result values

Comment: @Dukeling: I've decided to retract the second suggestion as there are lots of little subtleties that I don't have the energy to address in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the value range of an integer in java.

> The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of > -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive)

use a `long` instead of `int`

Comment: i actually tried with the long also still not getting the answer